# Combining two spark dataframes based on a column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have two data frames:

```
df1 = 

    | city    | timestamp           | value |
     ---------------------------------
    |  a      | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |  1    | 
    |  a      | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 |  2    |
    |  b      | 2018-01-01 10:00:00 |  1    | 
    |  b      | 2018-01-01 20:00:00 |  3    |
    |  c      | 2019-01-01 10:00:00 |  2    |
    |  a      | 2018-01-01 20:00:00 |  5    |
    |  c      | 2018-01-01 10:00:00 |  7    |
    |  b      | 2017-01-01 20:00:00 |  10   |


df2 = 

    | city    | timestamp           | value | ref_timestamp
     ---------------------------------
    |  a      | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |  1    | 2018-01-01 00:00:00
    |  a      | 2019-01-01 20:00:00 |  2    | 2018-01-01 20:00:00
    |  b      | 2019-01-01 10:00:00 |  1    | 2018-01-01 10:00:00
    |  b      | 2018-01-01 20:00:00 |  3    | 2017-01-01 20:00:00
    |  c      | 2019-01-01 10:00:00 |  2    | 2018-01-01 10:00:00
```

I need to join these 2 dataframes to get the following df

```
df3 = 

    | city    | timestamp           | value | ref_timestamp        | ref_value
     ---------------------------------
    |  a      | 2019-01-01 00:00:00 |  1    | 2018-01-01 00:00:00  | 2
    |  a      | 2019-01-01 20:00:00 |  2    | 2018-01-01 20:00:00  | 5
    |  b      | 2019-01-01 10:00:00 |  1    | 2018-01-01 10:00:00  | 1
    |  b      | 2018-01-01 20:00:00 |  3    | 2017-01-01 20:00:00  | 10
    |  c      | 2019-01-01 10:00:00 |  2    | 2018-01-01 10:00:00  | 7
```

Basically, it uses the ref_timestamp and queries it in df1 in the timestamp column and gets the value for it.

Answer (score 0):

df1 = df1.withColumnRenamed("value", "ref_value").withColumnRenamed("timestamp", "ref_timestamp")

df3 = df1.join(df2, ["city", "ref_timestamp"], "leftouter").where("timestamp is not null and value is not null")

Result: df3.show()

````
|city|      ref_timestamp|ref_value|          timestamp|value|
+----+-------------------+---------+-------------------+-----+
|   a|2018-01-01 00:00:00|        2|2019-01-01 00:00:00|    1|
|   a|2018-01-01 20:00:00|        5|2019-01-01 20:00:00|    2|
|   b|2018-01-01 10:00:00|        1|2019-01-01 10:00:00|    1|
|   b|2017-01-01 20:00:00|       10|2018-01-01 20:00:00|    3|
|   c|2018-01-01 10:00:00|        7|2019-01-01 10:00:00|    2|
+----+-------------------+---------+-------------------+-----+```
````

Comment: Throws an error at line 3: u"using columns ['city_id,'timestamp_local] can not be resolved given input columns:

Comment: @blackmamba Sorry I have not tested earlier.Updated the answer with test result as well

Answer (score 0):

A join on city and timestamps should do it:

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, (df1['city'] == df2['city']) and df1['time_stamp'] == df2['ref_tikme_stamp']
```

Then you just need to rename/drop columns to get the names as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

So, the following worked for me which avoids having duplicates in the list of columns.

```
df1 = df1.withColumnRenamed('timestamp', 'ref_timestamp').withColumnRenamed('value', 'ref_value')
df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed('timestamp', 'ref_timestamp')
df3 = df2.join(df1, ['city_id', 'ref_timestamp'])
```